# RequireJS - Execute a function on a module after it's loaded

Tags: requirejs

I'm trying to have one instance of socket.js for my project. I'm trying something like this:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        baseUrl: "../",
        socketio: `http://${window.location.host}/socket.io/socket.io`
    },
    shim: {
        "socketio": {
            init: function(socketio){
                console.log("this doesn't get logged anywhere");
                return socketio.connect(`http://${window.location.host}`);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the init doesn't seem to get called at all so I assume I'm misunderstanding its purpose. Regardless, is there any way I can make this simple connect call *once* before using socketio in my other files?

**Edit:** Just found that shim is related to targeting older browsers so I'm definitely using it wrong. Still, think it helps illustrate what I'm trying to do so I'll leave it in.

Comment: The reason it does not work is the same as the question against which I closed yours (`socket.io` calls `define` so you cannot use a `shim` for it) and the solution is the same: create a "glue" module that acts on the original module in whatever way you need and setup `map` so that your "glue" module is loaded whenever your modules call for the original module, but have the `map` set so that the glue module can get the original module.

Comment: Regarding your edit: `shim` is not a matter of being on an older browser or newer one. It is used when you want to use a script that does not call `define` and need to set dependencies for that module or specify what exactly to export from that script, or perform some special action through `init`.